# $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, e^{i \alpha_n t} \rightarrow 1 \implies \alpha_n \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$\alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed sequence of real numbers, for which the following holds:

$$
\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}e^{i\alpha_nt} = 1
$$

Is it necessarily the case that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n = 0$?

Comment: no reason to downvote here.

Comment: Of course, convergence for one fixed $t$, the answer is no as we have seen.  But here we want convervence for all $t$.

Comment: The question and the title do not match.  Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @anorton: I revised the title. Hopefully it matches the question closer. However, to be absolutely clear: it is the question (rather than the title) that I'm interested in.

Comment: What if you just look at $t$ of the form $1/k$? You then get that $\alpha_n$ has to converge to $0$ modulo $2\pi k$ as $n\to \infty$ for each $k\geq 1$. It seems like the only way this is possible is if $\alpha_n\to 0$....

Comment: $\lim e^{i\alpha_n t} \rightarrow 1$ makes more sense.

Comment: @i707107: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @i707107: a limit doesn't converge... it *equals* something. sequences converge.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683507/convergence-of-series-of-functions-f-nx-u-n-sinnx

Comment: @Max That's my mistake. OP has the correct edit though.

Comment: ye, sorry, mathematicians are pedants :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume (as we may) that $\alpha_n\neq 0$ for all $n$. By the dominated convergence theorem and the assumption on $\alpha_n$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 e^{i\alpha_n t}dt=1\, .$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_0^1e^{i\alpha_n t}dt=\frac{1}{i\alpha_n} (e^{i\alpha_n}-1)\, .$$
Since $e^{i\alpha_n}-1\to 0$, it follows that $\alpha_n\to 0$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Comment: Amazingly neat.

Comment: Thanks for the comments...

Comment: Just a little mistake on $1/(i\alpha_n)$... but, a Very nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

The convergence of $e^{i\alpha_n t}$ to $1$ implies the convergence of each component (real and imaginary part):
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}sin(\alpha_nt)=0$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}cos(\alpha_nt)=1$$
If we take $\alpha$ as the limit of $\alpha_n$ distinct of $0$ and take $t=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ by continuity of the functions cos and sin the limit have to be $cos(1)$ and $sin(1)$ then we have a contradiction with the original statement. And then we have two options: or $\alpha_n$ converges to $0$ or not converges.

If $\alpha_n$ have a convergent subsequence for each one of they we could apply the same argument an we have that limit points are $0$ then the problem is reducted to demostrate a contradiction in having a not convergent subsequence.

If the subsequence $\alpha_{n_k} \rightarrow \infty$ like @GEdgar said is a contradiction with the convergence of sin or cos (because the limit at infinity of both functions is not defined at infinity). Finally by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229105/limit-of-a-sequence-bounded-below-but-has-no-cluster-points) the subsequence not having cluster points and being bounded converges to infinity, again a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha_n$ be a sequence such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{i \alpha_n t} = 1\qquad\text{for all } t \in \mathbb R .
\tag{1}
$$
Suppose $\alpha_n$ does not converge to zero.  Replacing some $\alpha_n$ by $-\alpha_n$ if necessary, and taking a subsequence if necessary: we may assume there is $K>0$ so that $\alpha_n \ge K$ for all $n$.  Next, we may assume $\alpha \to \infty$: if not, there is a bounded subsequence, say $\alpha_n \le L$, and then $t = \pi/L$ contradicts the convergence (1) along that subsequence.

Now, for each $N \in \mathbb N$, define
$$
E_N = \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \left\{t \in \mathbb R \colon \left|
e^{i\alpha_n t}-1\right| \le \frac{1}{10}\right\} .
$$
The sets $E_N$ are closed, but by (1) we have
$$
\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} E_N = \mathbb R .
$$
By the Baire Category Theorem, some set $E_N$ is somewhere dense: there is an interval $(a,b) \subseteq E_N$, say.  But since $\alpha_n \nearrow \infty$, there is $n \ge N$ so that $\alpha_n(b-a) > 2\pi$.  This means
$$
\{e^{i \alpha_n t}\colon t \in (a,b)\}
$$
covers the entire circle, so
$$
\left|e^{i\alpha_n t}-1\right| < \frac{1}{10}
$$
fails for some $t \in E_N$.  Contradiction.

Comment: "we may assume there is $K>0$ so that $\alpha_n \ge K$ for all $n$." Don't you mean: "for infinitely many $n$"?

Comment: Nice. This also solves my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Evan: yes, edited.

Answer (score 0):

$\exp$ is $2\pi i$ periodically, so the answer is No. (if you mean $t\rightarrow\infty$)

edit: see comments

Comment: I was interpreting the question to mean $t\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed, and $n\to \infty$. There is actually some work to do here, I think....

Comment: ah okay... then still $t\alpha_{n}$ can have multiple cluster points around multiples of $2\pi$

Comment: yes, but then if you choose $t = 1/2$, then you wouldn't get the convergence to $1$ (unless I misunderstand something)

Comment: But what about convergence of $e^{i \alpha_n t}$ for all $t$?

Comment: if that convergence holds for all $t$ with the same series $\alpha_{n}$ then it should be possible to show that $\alpha_{n}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: the question has been edited

Comment: maybe you could use continuity of $p\mapsto p^{\frac{1}{t}}$ for $t>0$ (this is just a guess)

Comment: "should be" ... but "needs proof".

Comment: yes but that would be work... you might want to consider several cases:  convergent subsequence and sequence has no clusterpoints, i think i would start from there.